# Validate textarea in html with java script

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

I'm trying to prevent users from inputting and submitting single quotes ( ' ) into the textarea. below is what I have, but it isn't work.

```
    <script>
    function valtxtarea() {
        var val = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

        if ('\''.test(val)) {
            alert('do not add single qoutes to your inputs!');
        }
    }

</script>

<form>
    enter text below
    <textarea>input contents here</textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="valtxtarea();" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521559/validation-of-textarea

Comment: [.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is for regular expressions what you have is a string, did you mean to do `/'/.test(val)`. You should have been getting a `.test is not a function` or similar error on your browser's developer tools console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `id` attribute as well as the regex isn't valid

```js
function valtxtarea() {
  var val = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

  if (/\'/.test(val)) {
    alert('do not add single qoutes to your inputs!');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  enter text below
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="button" onclick="valtxtarea();" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: How do I add other characters like ),(,%. A link to a tutorial if any will be fine.

Comment: u need to check regex tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, why not prevent them from even typing it?

```
  <form>
  enter text below
  <textarea id='inputText' oninput="valtxtarea();"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="send">
  </form>

  <script>
  var oldValue = "input contents here";
  document.getElementById('inputText').value = oldValue;
  function valtxtarea() {
    var textArea = document.getElementById('inputText');
    if (textArea.value.match(/.*\'.*/g)) {
        textArea.value = oldValue;
    } else {
      oldValue = textArea.value;
    }
  }
  </script>
```

With this every time they type a char it is check and if it contains a ' then it sets it back to the old value. You could easily expand it to include other characters you do not want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
```

There is no HTML element with the id `textarea`.

Do something like this:

```
<textarea id="textarea">input contents here</textarea>
```

Also you probably want to prevent form submission if there is a validation error, so put `return false;` in the `if` in `valtxtarea()` and put `return valtxtarea()` in the onclick.